# scanf and printf 10 numbers in array only with INTIGER POINTERS //cant use intiger rather then A[]. +1 more

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this assignment:

> Write a C program (main function) which first reads 10 integers from the user inside an array A[10] and then prints these numbers on one line. Apart from the array A[] you can use only integer pointers in your program. No other variables are allowed.

My attempt is this:

```
int main()
{
    int A[10];
    int *i;

    printf("please type your 10 numbers\n");
    *i=0;
        while (*i<11)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[*i]);
        *i=*i+1;
    }
    *i=0;
while (*i<11)
{
printf("%d ",A[*i]);
*i=*i+1;
}
return 0;

}
```

But even compailer is not giving any error, exe is shutting itself. I hope someone will help me to fix it and also to understand my mistake.

> I have another task that is to write the following C function:
>    int count_interval( int A[], int *last, int lower, int upper )
>   which returns the number of elements of A which are larger than or equal to `lower` and smaller than or equal to `upper` (`lower ≤ A[i] ≤ upper`). The function does not receive the size of the array, instead it receives a
>   pointer (`last`) to the last element of the array.
>   main function should print 
>   The number of elements of A which are in the interval [10, 20],
>   The number of “5”s in the first half of A,
>   The number of elements in the second half of A which are larger than 50.

This is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//b
int count_interval(int *a, int *last, int lower, int upper)
{
    int *ptr;
    int *ilk=a;
    int *son=last;
    int k, count=0;

    for(; ilk!=son ;son--)
        if(*son>=lower && *son<=upper)
            count++;
    if(*son>=lower && *son<=upper)
        count++;
    return count;
}

//a
int count_interval(int *a, int *last, int lower, int upper);

int main()
{
    int SIZE;
    int a[10] = (50,10,5,23,25,5,15,80,22,66); //getting error here
    int k, n;
    int numberoffive=0;
    int numberoffifty=0;
    SIZE=10

    for(k=0; k<SIZE ;k++)
        for(k=0; k<SIZE/2 ;k++)
            printf("first half %d\n",a[k]);
    printf("\n");
    for(; k<SIZE ;k++)
        printf("second half %d\n",a[k]);

    if(a[k] < 20 && a[k] > 10)
        printf("between 10-20\n",a[k]); // not so sure about here 

    for(k=0, n=5; n>=0 ; n--,a[k++])
        if( a[k]==5 )
            numberoffive++;
    printf("\n5's in first half = %d \n",numberoffive);

    for(k=5, n=5; n>=0 ; n--,a[k++])
        if( a[k]>50 )
            numberoffifty++;
    printf("\nlarger then 50 in second half = %d\n", numberoffifty);

    printf("\n Counter= %d\n",count_interval(a ,&a[SIZE-1],10,20));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You should describe the errors more carefully.  In the first program, you have problems because your `int *` doesn't point to anything (points to null), but then you try to use it.  You should also heed the warnings from your compiler; you shouldn't try running code while the compiler is giving you warnings.

Comment: "an error" is not very useful information. Please [edit] your question to say what the error actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i` is not pointing to anything.  You should really do something like

```
int *i=A

scanf("%d",i);

++i;
```

and test for `I<&A[10]`

But it's a crappy, contrived question.  If you need to accept 10 values, then just do it in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   10

void input_array( int *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        scanf( "%i", a );
        input_array( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}

void print_array( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "%i ", *a );
        print_array( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}

size_t count_interval( const int *first, const int *last, int lower, int upper )
{
    return first == last 
        ? 0 
        : ( lower <= *first && *first <= upper ) 
          + count_interval( first + 1, last, lower, upper );  
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];

    printf( "please type your %zu numbers: ", ( size_t )N );

    input_array( a, N );

    putchar( '\n' );
    print_array( a, N );
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "%zu\n", count_interval( a, a + N, 3, 7 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
please type your 10 numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
5
```

Or the functions `input_array` and `print_array` can be defined using only pointers like

```
void input_array( int *first, int *last )
{
    if ( first != last )
    {
        scanf( "%i", first );
        input_array( first + 1, last );
    }
}

void print_array( const int *first, const int *last )
{
    if ( first != last )
    {
        printf( "%i ", *first );
        print_array( first + 1, last );
    }
}
```

In this case they should be called like for example

```
input_array( a, a + N );
```

and

```
print_array( a, a + N );
```

As for you code then apart from syntax errors like for example this

```
int a[10] = (50,10,5,23,25,5,15,80,22,66); 
           ^^^                         ^^^
```

already these statements

```
int *i;

printf("please type your 10 numbers\n");
*i=0;
```

lead to undefined behavior because the variable `i` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

Also it is unclear why you are using the magic number 11.

And in any case you are using the subscript operator instead of pointers.

In fact all what you need in the both assignments is the following loop

```
for ( int *first = A; first != A + 10; ++first )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: seems like i mixed them all up :D they were 2 different questions, as i typed 2 codes they belonged to 2 different questions :D

Comment: @EgeÇıkrıkçı It is unimportant how many questions are there. It is important how many tasks are there. And I showed one of approaches how the task can be performed.:)

Comment: in your code i saw that u used this line;
count_interval( const int *first, const int *last, int lower, int upper ) which belongs to another task.

one task was to read and write 10 numbers in array w/0 using intigers but pointers.

another one was to write the following C function:

int count_interval( int A[], int *last, int lower, int upper )
which returns the number of elements of A which are larger than or equal to lower and smaller than or equal to upper (lower ≤ A[i] ≤ upper). The function does not receive the size of the array, instead it receives a pointer (last)..

Comment: @EgeÇıkrıkçı It is one of your tasks to write the corresponding function and I showed in one demonstrative program how all the tasks can be performed. I was not going to write instead of you all your code.:) What is unclear with the function?

Comment: okey i though you kinda mixed it up but yeah it wasnt my intent. it just confused me a little bit :D thank you by the way.